# Populating a PostgreSQL database with Python error

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sql-injection

I'm trying to populate a database, but am getting a syntax error.

I have multiple lists with data, with several lists that include those lists.

```
injury_act_1 = ('2017-01-16 15:36:38','Injury','Unsafe Act', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'While lifting a 50 lb item from the floor onto their wokrstation, the employee felt a sharp pain in their lower back.','The employee ran out of room on their workstation because the takeaway conveyor was inoperable')
```

This repeats for 10 times. There are more lists for action items for those injuries, audits, and action items for those audits.

I have a function to insert these into my database.

```
def populate():
    params = config()
    # connect to the PostgreSQL server
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = safety")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    for i in range(len(injuries)):
        incident = (
            """
            INSERT INTO incident (
                            date_time,
                            incident_type,
                            incident_cat,
                            injury,
                            property_damage,
                            description,
                            root_cause
                            )
                VALUES (
                    """+ injuries[i][0] +""",
                    """+ injuries[i][1] +""",
                    """+ injuries[i][2] +""",
                    """+ injuries[i][3] +""",
                    """+ injuries[i][4] +""",
                    """+ injuries[i][5] +""",
                    """+ injuries[i][6] +"""
            """)

        cur.execute(incident)
        print("Injury case added!")

        action_items = (
            """
            INSERT INTO action_items (
                            case_id,
                            finding,
                            corrective_action
                            )
                VALUES (
                    """+ (i+1) +""",
                    """+ injuries[i][4] +". "+ injuries[i][5] +""",
                    """+ actions[i] +""",
                    )

            """
            )

        cur.execute(action_items)
        print("Action item added!")

    for j in range(len(audits)):
        audit = (
            """
            INSERT INTO audit (
                            date_time,
                            type,
                            que_1,
                            que_2,
                            que_3,
                            ans_1,
                            ans_2,
                            ans_3,
                            )
                VALUES (
                    """+ str(audits[i][0]) +""",
                    """+ audits[i][1] +""",
                    """+ audits[i][2] +""",
                    """+ audits[i][3] +""",
                    """+ audits[i][4] +""",
                    """+ audits[i][5] +""",
                    """+ audits[i][6] +""",
                    """+ audits[i][7] +"""
            """
            )

        cur.execute(audit)
        print("Audit added!")

        action_items_a = (
            """
            INSERT INTO action_items (
                            audit_id,
                            finding,
                            corrective_action
                            )
                VALUES (
                    """+ (i+1) +""",
                    'Audit deficiency',
                    """+ actions_a[i] +""",
                    )
            """
            )

        cur.execute(action_items_a)
        print("Action item added!")

    cur.close()
    conn.commit()

populate()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "database_populator.py", line 204, in <module>
        populate()
    File "database_populator.py", line 137, in populate
        cur.execute(incident)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "15"
Line 12:        2017-01-16 15:36:38,
                            ^
```

Comment: Instead of munging the query string, use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a step back here and look at how you'e forming the query. Try to avoid using string concatenation for query building, and especially for user-supplied input of any kind. It's not only bug-prone (as you have found) but [a security nightmare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Your code should use [psycopg2's bind parameter support](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html), looking more like:

```
incident = (
            """
            INSERT INTO incident (
                            date_time,
                            incident_type,
                            incident_cat,
                            injury,
                            property_damage,
                            description,
                            root_cause
                            )
                VALUES (""" + (["%s"] * 7).join(", ") + ")"
    cur.execute(incident, injuries)
```

so that it lets psycopg2 take care of the escaping and formatting.

You can write out seven literal `%s`s, like `%s, %s, %s, ...` if you want. I just prefer the above form.

This way if someone tricks your app into accepting a string in `injuries`, like say `');DROP TABLE incident;--`, you won't be in such trouble.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer. This program was just for me to use to fill in the database so I can test the web app. However, I'd be coming up on this problem eventually once I start setting up the user input functions. Like you said, it's good to practice healthy habits!

Comment: @JTP709 It's also better for log analysis, performance, and for reducing bugs.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to construct the query string yourself (which is a bad idea), enclose dates in quotation marks:

```
"""
    ....
    VALUES (
                '"""+ injuries[i][0] +"""',
                '"""+ injuries[i][1] +"""',
                '"""+ injuries[i][2] +"""',
                '"""+ injuries[i][3] +"""',
                '"""+ injuries[i][4] +"""',
                '"""+ injuries[i][5] +"""',
                '"""+ injuries[i][6] +"""'
        """)
```

Still better, construct the query with a list comprehension:

```
"""
    ....     
    VALUES(""" + ",".join("'{}'".format(injury) for injury in injuries[i]) + ")"
```

Comment: Whyyyy wouldn't you just show the correct way? Or at least link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @CraigRinger Because I answer the OP's question. You have your answer? Post it.

Comment: Let me put that another way. Please when you see such terribly insecure coding practices, bring the matter to the poster's attention rather than doubling down on unsafe practices without comment.

Comment: Is saying "(which is a bad idea)" not bringing the matter to the poster's attention?